# unix ftp transfer mget path not found

Tags: unix, ftp, ksh

I use below code to transfer files from ftp machine to local machine. I run this code from local machine

```
   #check path exists in local 
   if [[ -d /ahome/data/tt/ftp ]] then
        print "$scriptname path exists" 1>&2;
    fi
    #output run.ksh  path exists

    #Create if path not exists in Local
    if [[ ! -d /ahome/data/tt/ftp ]] then
        print "$scriptname  /ftp not found.create" 1>&2;
        mkdir /ahome/data/tt/ftp
    fi  

    #transfer files from ftp.inf.com to local path
    ftp -i ftp.inf.com  << FTP_START
        cd /infhome/upload/tt
        mget new* /ahome/data/tt/ftp/
        bye
    FTP_START
    #error  /ahome/data/tt/ftp the system cannot find the path specified
```

Because of the error it copies the files to the same directory where the run.ksh is placed. Unable to figure out why. Is it checking for the path somewhere else

Comment: `mget` doesn't accept a destination directory. Use `lcd destinationdir` then `mget new*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer mentioned in the comment by Mark.

get allows to copy single file from ftp. The syntax is below

```
cd [remote dir]
get remote-file [local-file-with-path]
```

mget copies multiple files from remote to local. We need to mention the destination directory using lcd command

```
cd [remote dir]
lcd [local dir]
mget fileprefix*
```

Refer [this](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#get) link also